# how can I remove the gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I list the users in my database using javascript and php.There are gaps between them. How can I remove the gap .You can see in the picture thing I want

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnmn3.png)

**JavaScript**

```js
$(function(){
    $(".form-control").keyup(function() { 
        var searchid = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'form-control='+ searchid;
        if(searchid!='')
        {
           $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "search.php",
             data: dataString,
             cache: false,
             success: function(html)
             {
               $("#result").html(html).show();
             }
           });
       }
       return false;    
    });

    jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
        $('#searchid').val(decoded);
    });

    jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.hasClass("form-control")){
            jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
        }
    });

    $('#searchid').click(function(){
        jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
    #searchid
    {
    }

    #result
    {
        position:absolute;
        width: 100%;
        padding:0px;
        display:none;
        margin-top:-1px;
        z-index: 1000;
        border-top:0px;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:1px #CCC solid;
        background-color: white;    
    }

    .show2
    {
        background-color: red;
        font-size:30px; 
        border:10px #CCC solid;
    }

    .show2:hover
    {
        background:#4c66a4;
        color:#FFF;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchid"  placeholder="Arama" >
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: What html is `search.php` returning?

Comment: <?php

if($_POST)
{
$q=$_POST['form-control'];

 
  
  
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE kullaniciadi  like '%$q%' limit 0,6";
  
 $result =    $vt->query($query);
 
 $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 
 
 

 
 $temp_array  = array();
 
 
 if($number_of_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   
   
   ?>
   <hr>
   <?php
   $temp_array[] = $row;
  
   
   ?>
 <div class="show2" align="left">
 <span class="name"><?php echo $row['kullaniciadi']; ?></span>
 </div>
 <?php

Comment: Instead of pasting it in the comments, it would be much more readable if you could edit your question with the code. From an initial look at the code, could you remove `<hr>` from `search.php` and see if there's any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess your used `<p/>` for every `.show` element. So there is have a default margin style.

Try this (set *margin: 0;* for every element with class `show`):

```css
#searchid
    {
    }

    #result
    {
        position:absolute;
        width: 100%;
        padding:0px;
        display:none;
        margin-top:-1px;
        z-index: 1000;
        border-top:0px;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:1px #CCC solid;
        background-color: white;    
    }

    .show2
    {
        background-color: red;
        font-size:30px; 
        border:10px #CCC solid;
        margin:0;
    }

    .show2:hover
    {
        background:#4c66a4;
        color:#FFF;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchid"  placeholder="Arama" >
<div id="result" style="display:block"><!-- i overide style to display block for try, remove attribute display -->
<p class='show2'>i used P</p>
<div class='show2'>i used div</div>
<div class='show2'>i used div</div>
</div>
```